# How can I train my LSTM model with multiple datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, lstm, sequential

I have 1000 datasets that has the battery voltage of different devices. eg: device1.csv, device2.csv....etc.

Each dataset is sequential as it has a feature; the battery voltage measured at every age of the device. I want to train a single LSTM model with all those datasets without breaking my sequence.

The shape of every dataset is different therefore I cannot stack merge them into one dataframe.

Should I train the model in a for loop?

Comment: Somehow you shall share some code so one can better help you.

Comment: Each dataset is one training example?

Comment: @AndrzejO yes, each dataset is one training sample of one device. I want to train the model with multiple such datasets of different devices. All the datasets share similar columns but with different values and varying timestamps.